# Autodesk Viewer: Show a list of elements with specified Database IDs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The functionality I seek is very similar to the default ModelStructurePanel model browser, except that I need to list only a subset of elements, by passing a list of dbIds of the elements I want listed. By clicking on an element on that list, have the view focus on that element.
I figure there might be two ways of achieving this by using the ModelStructurePanel (although I'm open to using something else):

- Creating a new instanceTree with only the specified elements, then doing something like *viewer.modelstructure.setModel(newInstanceTree)*
- Overwriting the *ModelStructurePanel.shouldInclude* method to hide all elements but the specified ones.

I have googled for Viewer code boilerplate that would provide this functionality, but have not found it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [basic sample here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customizing-modelstructurepanel-behavior-forge-viewer) very close to what you described, and I would go with customizing just one action instead create a new one, seems easier.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a useful link. However, I am not looking to change the default behavior options for something else, the default behavior is actually fine for me. I'd like to show, in the tree view, a custom list which contains only a limited subset of elements of the whole model tree.